# Interpreting discrimination values in IRT polytomous (grm) models. Are there any cut-offs or anchors?

Tags: r, likert, item-response-theory

I am working on a project that is looking at the discriminative properties of 6, 5-point Likert items in a scale. I am using the ltm package in R to examine this within a item response theory (irt) paradigm, using a graded response model (grm).

For each item, I am given a "discrimination value" that corresponds with the slope of the ICC at each level given the ability level. For my six items, the values are (approximately): 2.1, 1.8, 1.3, 0.8, 2.7, 2.3.

How would I interpret these? Is there a cut-off for "good" discriminative properties? Are there values related to "weak", "medium", or "strong" levels of discrimination?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent many more hours on this problem and eventually came up with guidelines presented in Baker (2001):

Baker, F. (2001). The basics of item response theory. ERIC Clearinghouse on Assessment and Evaluation, University of Maryland College Park, MD.

It seems that '*a*' representing an item's discrimination, has values that are synonymous for both dichotomous and polytomous data. Discrimination is classified as 'none','low','moderate', 'high', and 'perfect'. The ranges are as follows:
0 is 'none'
0.01-0.34 is 'very low';
0.35-0.64 is 'low';
0.65-1.34 is 'moderate';
1.35-1.69 is 'high';
=> 1.7 is 'very high'
+ infinity is 'perfect'